# Firebase Class FIRAAppEnvironmentUtil is implemented in both when using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to use Firebase inside a dynamic framework (Cocoa Touch Framework). I've added Firebase to the Podfile like so:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'Test.xcworkspace'

target 'Test' do
  project 'Test.xcodeproj'
end

target 'TestFramework' do
  project 'TestFramework/TestFramework.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for TestFramework
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

And I've set a target dependency in the build phase of my Test target. All according to: https://github.com/benasher44/CocoaPodsLibExample

However when I reference my TestFramework from my Test target during app startup I get this message (for all the Firebase classes) in the console:

> objc[34978]: Class FIRAAppEnvironmentUtil is implemented in both
>   /Users/peterwarbo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-goxvmnklbfyswhdniydzbvzudcez/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
>   (0x1085858c8) and
>   /Users/peterwarbo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43080C45-C9E9-4237-A255-5029CC4D5797/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FCFDC439-8564-40A8-9B34-935FE222193E/Test.app/Test
>   (0x104342938). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

And the app crashes. I've read that this might have something to do with that Firebase is a static library. I need to solve this so I can use my use Firebase from my different targets. Specifically what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to do Firebase operations from a keyboard extension, so both my host app and my extension should be able to to perform Firebase operations.

I've been trying to solve this for more than a week now and I haven't come up with any working solutions :(

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1, Cocoapods 1.2.0

Comment: did you find any solution, now it's my turn , trying to solve this problem :)

Comment: could you please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642291/firebase-analytics-with-ios-framework-development-project