# Firebase Analytics with iOS framework development project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I am adding Firebase analytics using coocapods, my Podfile is

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'ProjectWorkspace.xcworkspace'

abstract_target 'Shows' do
    pod 'SwiftProtobuf', git: 'https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf.git', :tag => '0.9.24'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

    target 'HostApp' do
        project 'HostAppFolder/HostApp.xcodeproj'

    end
    target 'HostAppReleaseTarget' do
        project 'HostAppFolderApp/HostApp.xcodeproj'

    end

    target 'FrameWorkProject' do
        project 'FrameworkProjectFolder/FrameWorkProject.xcodeproj'
    end

end
```

if I add SwiftProtobuf only as dependency it's working fine for host application as well as for Framework project.

If I add Firebase dependency, I get a run-time error and the application crashes with error msg

> Class Foo is implemented in both, HostApplicationPath and FrameworkProjectPath One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

for each class file of Firebase.

when I remove other linker flags $(inherited) from framework project, it's work fine, but I can not use firebase into my framework project.

My framework and Host application is written in Swfit 3.0 and xcode version is 8.x

My Project structure is
i have created a workspace manually and named it "EVAWorkspace.xcworkspace" and added my host application and framework project into this workspace and then i am adding cocoapods to workspace.

[image: Project structure]

Eva is framework project and EvaApp is host application project.

Comment: Could  you please show what error you are getting when you try to use Firebase in your Framework?

Comment: And also please show your projects structure and dependencies: HostApplication and FrameworkProject.

Comment: thanks @DavidV , when i removed $(inherited) flags from framework project, i am getting error --> "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UtilityMethods.o"

Comment: modified my question to depict project structure

Comment: Did you try to add Firebase framework to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section in your framework project?

Comment: yes, actually pods(firebase) is common for framework and host project, and i don't want to create umbrella framework project

Comment: I guess you should add pod 'Firebase/Core' , pod 'Firebase/Messaging' under target 'FrameWorkProject' and  target 'HostApp' .

Comment: but as i said i don't wish to create umbrella framework, if i do so when exporting my SDKs it will contain Firebase/core and Firebase/Messaging with my SDKs thats not what i want.there is another pods(rocketSocket) also add in host application and it's working fine for framework project. it's happing due to firebase framework is static library made in objective-c

Comment: You have to link necessary framework with static library! Otherwise you have to use dynamic loading:
http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2015/10/17/static-libraries-and-embedded-frameworks/

Comment: @DavidV the blog link is broken, do you have another resource link ?

Comment: @NicolasMassart, sorry it was long ago, even don't remember what it was about. What is your current issue? Can I help you?

Comment: @DavidV perhaps :) I would like to use Firebase in a framework that I will distribute to a client that already have firebase in his app and every attempts I do fails as my framework includes firebase and conflicts with the app firebase. I would like to use cocoapods for my framework but this is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying each of the following, use the **"Clean Build Folder"** option in XCode to ensure you're getting a clean build each time. If you want to be *really* sure, you can delete the `DerivedData` folder in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` before starting (just make sure Xcode is closed when you delete it)

First of all, ensure that your Pods project has "Build Active Architecture Only" set to `NO` in its Build settings. Then try cleaning the build folder and rebuilding. This might solve your issue, otherwise read on.

The most common reason for the problem you have described: "Undefined symbols for architecture X" is that you've imported a library in your code but have not linked against it correctly.

to solve this, you should either:

- Add the library to ***"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"*** in your ***"BuildPhases"***
- Add the library's path to ***"Library Search Paths"*** under Build Settings, and then add `"-l{your library} to "***Other Linker Flags***".

If this does not solve your problem, it might be that the linker is not getting the required flags. You could try adding $(inherited) back to the ***"Other Linker Flags"*** section of Build Settings.

Don't forget to clean your build folder before trying each of these techniques.

If after doing all this your problem still persists, please delete all Cocoapods created files in your project and then post the output of `pod install --verbose` here.

Comment: having same issue , can you please share more update on it